# List of dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular2 and I'm trying to add form fields dynamically and recover all the user informations.

I have this component (that I try to re-use)

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'text-form',
  templateUrl: './text.component.html'
})
export class TextComponent implements OnInit{
  textForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.textForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      value: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.textForm.getRawValue()));
  }

}
```

I have then the following html (about.component.html)

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" (click)="addField(1)">Add text!</a></p>
<p *ngFor="let type of forms">
  <text-form></text-form>
</p>
```

and the associate ts for this page html (about.component.ts)

```
export class AboutComponent {  
  forms: number[]=[];

  constructor() {}

   addField(type:number): void {
     this.forms.push(type);
  }

}
```

When I press on the button, I have a new form in my html which is nice. But I have no idea how can I iterate over all my `text-form` in order to get back then content.

I have also tried to instanciate directly the `TextComponent` and then iterate over it but it was not working as expected.

about.component.ts

```
   addField(type:number): void {

     let tmp = new TextComponent(new FormBuilder());
     this.forms.push(tmp);
}
```

But when I try to display the content I am just getting
`[object Object]`

I have also tried to use this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview
I understand the setter part but I really don't know how to instanciate a new component (from a factory or directly)

Thanks for your help